# Google Cloud Build Error: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

Note: There is a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61312014/google-cloud-build-trigger-failing-with-error-build-step-0-gcr-io-cloud-build) regarding this issue but it involves a CI/CD workflow and a considerably more complicated Dockerfile. The solutions presented do not seem to apply to my situation.

Per [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service) I am attempting to build an image by running `gcloud run deploy` in the directory where the files mentioned in my Dockerfile are located. The Dockerfile appears as:

```
FROM python:3.9-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY main.py /app/main.py
COPY requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

I receive a message that the build failed, and when checking the logs I see the following:

```
starting build "..."

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://my-app_cloudbuild/source/....
Copying gs://my-app_cloudbuild/source/...
/ [0 files][    0.0 B/  1.5 KiB]                                                
/ [1 files][  1.5 KiB/  1.5 KiB]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/1.5 KiB.                                      
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Can anyone explain the reason for this error? I suspect it has to do with how files are copied to the image, but I was able to build and run this container without problem on my local machine. Any idea why this fails in Cloud Run Build?

Running `ls -la` in the directory where I ran `gcloud run deploy` returns:

```
drwxr-xr-x   9 user  staff       288 May 20 16:04 .
drwxr-xr-x   6 user  staff       192 May 20 13:35 ..
drwxr-xr-x  14 user  staff       448 May 20 16:06 .git
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff        27 May 20 15:06 .gitignore
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff       424 May 20 16:54 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff      3041 May 20 15:55 main.py
-rw-r--r--   1 user  staff       144 May 19 09:42 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x   6 user  staff       192 May 19 09:09 venv
```

Contents of `.gitignore`:

```
Dockerfile
venv
*.gz
*.tar
*.pem
```

Full console output when attempting two-step build (see comments):

```
user@users-MacBook-Pro TwitterBotAQI % gcloud builds submit  --tag gcr.io/missoula-aqi/aqi
Creating temporary tarball archive of 2 file(s) totalling 3.1 KiB before compression.
Some files were not included in the source upload.

Check the gcloud log [/Users/user/.config/gcloud/logs/2022.05.20/18.40.53.921436.log] to see which files and the contents of the
default gcloudignore file used (see `$ gcloud topic gcloudignore` to learn
more).

Uploading tarball of [.] to [gs://missoula-aqi_cloudbuild/source/1653093653.998995-48d4ba15b3274455a21e16b7abc7d65b.tgz]
Created [https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com/v1/projects/missoula-aqi/locations/global/builds/0c22d976-171e-4e7b-92d8-ec91704d6d52].
Logs are available at [https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/0c22d976-171e-4e7b-92d8-ec91704d6d52?project=468471228522].
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ REMOTE BUILD OUTPUT -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
starting build "0c22d976-171e-4e7b-92d8-ec91704d6d52"

FETCHSOURCE
Fetching storage object: gs://missoula-aqi_cloudbuild/source/1653093653.998995-48d4ba15b3274455a21e16b7abc7d65b.tgz#1653093655000531
Copying gs://missoula-aqi_cloudbuild/source/1653093653.998995-48d4ba15b3274455a21e16b7abc7d65b.tgz#1653093655000531...
/ [1 files][  1.5 KiB/  1.5 KiB]                                                
Operation completed over 1 objects/1.5 KiB.
BUILD
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

BUILD FAILURE: Build step failure: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build 0c22d976-171e-4e7b-92d8-ec91704d6d52 completed with status "FAILURE"
```

Comment: I'd suggest posting as `ls -la` output in the directory where you run `gcloud run deploy`.  Maybe also post the complete output (assuming there is more) of the output.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the output showing directory contents. The only information I omitted from the logs pertained to hashes and/or UUIDs assigned by Google Cloud Run. I omitted these for readability. The only additional CLI output was `ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Build failed; check build logs for details` not very informative.

Comment: There is something missing in your question on how you are deploying. The error means there is no **Dockerfile** present to build the container. I recommend that you build and deploy as separate steps. Use **gcloud builds submit ...** first and then **gcloud run deploy ...** This will help you identify errors much faster.

Comment: I will try that, for reference I've used the following documentation for my approach:
https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service

Comment: @JohnHanley `gcloud builds submit` requires a `cloudbuild.yaml` file which I never saw referenced in the documentation linked above. I'm not saying your approach isn't valid, but I'm hoping to get a minimal example up and running by following the documentation.

Comment: **cloud builds submit** does not require cloudbuild.yaml. It only requires **--tag** to specify the image. If you review the error messages in your question, there is only one file in your build. That will not build a container (two files at least are required). Therefore, build from the command line, review the error message, repair and move to the next step. As I said, you have left an important detail or two out of your question.

Comment: Building with `docker build -t gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/aqi:v1 . ` and then passing this tag to `gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/my-project/my-app` resulted in the identical error to my original approach: `ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1`

Comment: Post the full console when you try the two step build. The “real” error is not the line you commented.

Comment: @stephen.vakil this has been posted

Comment: Notice that tarballs are being uploaded to `gs://missoula-aqi_cloudbuild/source/1653093653.998995-48d4ba15b3274455a21e16b7abc7d65b.tgz` (for example).  I'd suggest we see if those still exist and, if yes, download one and see what's in it.  I want to see that Dockerfile is being uploaded.  Next, I note the presence of a .gitignore.  Can we see the content of that too please.

Comment: @Kolban I've added the contents of `.gitignore` to this post. The tarballs referenced in the output can not be found in cloud storage contained in my project and were never created locally.

Comment: And there my friend is the puzzle.  Somehow the "Dockerfile" has been added to your .gitignore.  Remove "Dockerfile" from `.gitignore` and lets try again.

Comment: Excellent! That did the trick. I had added `Dockerfile` to `.gitignore` as it contained API keys set as environment variables.

Comment: @TedLavender, does the comments above solve your question? If yes, please post them as an answer so that the community with similar questions finds it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had added `Dockerfile` to `.gitignore` as it contained API keys stored as environment variables. Removing `Dockerfile` from `.gitignore` resolved the issue.